# Intercepting chrome-extension://*/?q=<input> in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So I am using the omnibox in my extension, and after a user enters something in the omnibox, it becomes part of the extensions "history" (which would be a nice feature). However, when the history entry is clicked on, it goes to "chrome-extension//?q=, and that returns an Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND). Is there any way to remedy this situation, either by allowing this to act as it did the first time, or just by disabling the history?

EDIT: so it turns out one cannot inject content scripts into chrome-extensions (even though the [documentation says you can](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html)  ([they're fixing this hopefully](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chromium-extensions/fd2OREQ_byA%5B1-25%5D))

Any other advice is still appreciated, but I've become less hopeful that this can be done.

Comment: Can you post the code that your omnibox integration is using as well as your manifest.json file?